# How can I switch users within an app in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build an app were I would like to switch between two android users (Alice (owner) and Bob). When Alice is the current user, I want to open the app and press a button and switch to Bob's account and vice-versa.)

I set up the app as a Device Administrator using the `DevicePolicyManager` class so I can use the `switchUser` method but I'm not understanding how I set the `userHandler` so I can switch users.

```
public class DevicePolicyAdmin extends Activity {
    protected static final int REQUEST_ENABLE = 1;
    DevicePolicyManager appDevicePolicyManager;
    ComponentName appDevicePolicyAdmin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_policy_admin);
        appDevicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        appDevicePolicyAdmin = new ComponentName(this,
                MyDevicePolicyReceiver.class);
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
        intent.putExtra(
                DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,
                appDevicePolicyAdmin);
        intent.putExtra(
                DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
                getString(R.string.admin_explanation));
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        appDevicePolicyManager.switchUser(appDevicePolicyAdmin, android.os.Process.myUserHandle());
    }
}
```

Another approach I tried was using the `AccountManager` class, but I can only get the currents user email. And this class does not seem to have a `switchUser` method.

```
AccountManager manager = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
Account[] list = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for (Account s : list)
{
    builder.append(s + " ");
}
setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_policy_admin);
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
txt.setText(builder.toString());
```

Here's a picture of what I am trying to implement.

[image: switch users android]

It's basically an app that does the same thing as if we would go to the Settings Menu > Users.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do this as an administrator.  Would it be sufficient to have Alice sign out so Bob could sign in?  Or does the administrator have to make the switch?

Comment: Each user should be able to make the switch. Example: Alice opens the app clicks a button and switches to user bob. Bob could also open the app and switch back to Alice.
I could try your approach. Make Alice sign out so Bob could sign in. Any ideas on how I could implement that. Just started learning android yesterday and I don't  know the API quite well.

Comment: What is the concept of "account" for your application? Do users have to authenticate against a server?  Do you have your own application server with accounts/passwords?  Or are you using a third-party like Facebook or Google?  Or do users not even need passwords at all?  How do accounts get created for the device? How do you decide, "okay, Alice gets an account and Bob gets an account".  Sorry for all the questions, this is all stuff that must be thought about for making the app.  A tall order for someone just starting on Android!  I can show you two ways: the hard way and the even harder way.

Comment: For now accounts are created locally and by hand. I have a phone, that starts with a user(owner) and manually create other accounts.
In the future the idea is that the app shows for example a QR code. The user scans the QR code with its mobile, I check the users credentials, stored in is phone, and send back the credentials authenticating the user in is account in the phone with multiple users. 
 
But for now I'm just trying to understand if android allows me to switch user accounts programmatically. Is it possible? How? I like hard tasks. It's the only way to learn...

Comment: Wait - just to get it straight - are the following statements correct? 1. You want to change useraccounts **inside** your app, only. 2. You do **not** want to change the useraccount for the whole device.

Comment: @Fildor I've added a picture of what I'm trying to implement. I want to switch between users in my phone. The same as if we would go to the settings menu > users and pressed a user name and switch to it's account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for now I'm just trying to understand if android allows me to switch user accounts programmatically.

Okay, I'm just going to address that part of the question, since you haven't said anything about a remote server and what part it plays.

The answer is: Yes, you can change accounts programmatically.  You can store account data in a SQLite database (the hard way) or internally using `AccountManager` (the even harder way).

**The Hard Way:**  Manage account data using a SQLite table.

If you don't need more sophisticated features like remote data sync in the background, you can define for yourself what an "account" means to your app.  There's nothing that requires you to use `AccountManager` features in your app.  You can have SQLite table(s) that hold username and whatever other data you need to associate with that user.  Keep in mind that your app will need some administrative functions to maintain the account table, so you will have to code that up as well.

Once you have data for each user account, you can even have an activity to list all the users and select the one to sign in with, if you want.

**The Even Harder Way:**  Write an account authenticator that plugs into the `AccountManager`.

I did this for my app, and it's a real challenge.  I wouldn't recommend it for someone like yourself who's just starting with Android, but you might need to if you want to use Android's remote data sync capabilities.

I refer everyone to this article as the best guide for working with Android authentication:  [Write your own Android Authenticator](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/)

Your app should have its own account type ("com.whatever"); you don't have to use the Google accounts.  Having a custom authenticator also lets you manage accounts from Settings | Accounts on the device, so you don't even have to run your app.  This is described in the article.

`AccountManager` and friends also provide a built-in activity to select an account from the list of accounts already on the device.

---

This is just an overview; as they say, the devil is in the details.  You have to work out what the flow is both for the user and for you as an administrator, how the app with work with the remote server (for example, with sessions), and if your design addresses all the security risks (how much exposure do I have if passwords are stored on the device?)

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer. "The even harder way" will come very handy in the second phase of my project.
One thing I still don't get is how I get the details for the second user. For example If Alice is logged in, I can't see Bob's details(account). (I tested with the examples provided in your link). But, for now, I'm going to leave the authentication for later. 
I'm going to try to implement the "Hard Way" because it seems more what I need right now.

Comment: Does it have to be a Google account? Can your app just have its own account type?  If your app has its own account type, then you can set it up so that Alice can be logged in to your app, but you can still see Bob's account details.

Comment: I believe the question was originally about Android users (which are usually handled via UserManager) and this answer is talking about Accounts, which is a different concept.